# How to show the result of a Javascript Function on a Dialog using a Button?

Tags: javascript, function, button

My question is How to show the result of a Javascript Function on a Dialog using a Button ?

Ty for u're help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
function yourfunction()
{
// code
return result;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="alert(yourfunction());">Click</button>
```

**DEMO**

```js
function myfunction()
{
  return "It works";  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert(myfunction())">Clic</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use jQuery UI dialog:

```js
function someFunction() {
  return 42;
}

$(function() {
  $('<div>' + someFunction() + '</div>').appendTo('body').dialog();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

HTML

```
<button id="button">
    Show results
</button>
```

JS

```
// The function whose results we want to print out
function foo() {
    var result = "bar";
    // we need to return the result
    return result;
}

// get the button in the HTML
var button = document.getElementById("button");

// attach the click event on it
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   // after clicking the button, show the results
   alert(foo());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v39honrp/2/